# Almost everywhere convergence for integral

Tags: measure-theory

I have a question about the following proof (from Rudin's RCA).

[image]

And, here are the Theorems 1.27 and 1.34
[image]
[image]

What I do not understand about Theorem 1.38 is the conclusion that the series $f(x)$ converges for almost all x.

The proof shows that f(x) converges absolutely for $x\in E$, hence it converges for $x\in E$. THe proof also shows that $\mu(E^c) = 0$.

So, if I let D be the set on which $f(x)$ does not converge, then I know that $D$ is a subset of $E^c$, so **IF** I know that $D$ is measurable, then I can conclude that $f(x)$ converges for almost all x, but how do I know that $D$ is measurable?

Answer (score 2):

The set where a sequence of measurable functions does not converge is measurable. Why? It's the complement of the set where the sequence converges, which is measurable. (On terminology: "$f(x)$ converges" doesn't really makes sense.)

Comment: How do you know that the set where the sequence converges is measurable? I only know that the set where the sequence converges absolutely is measurable

Comment: It's the set where $\limsup = \liminf.$

Answer (score 1):

Lebesgue measure is an example of a [complete measure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_measure#Examples), which means - very conveniently for your question! - that every subset of a measure-0 set is automatically measurable. (Indeed, the reason we use Lebesgue measure, in some sense, is because it's the complete measure most closely related to Borel sets.)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I didn't mean Lebesuge integral as in lebesgue measure, but "general" lebesgue integral as Rudin defines it